# Searching multiple text files for data

Tags: c#

Okay I have multiple text files which all contain data some text based some numerical. all the data is linked, so row one of one the text files is linked with row one of another text file and so on. I need to be able to search a year (one of the text files) and have all the data linked with that year be outputted to the console. As part of the requirement the text files have to stay separate. How would you recommend I go by this??
Here is what I have so far.

```
case 8:
                    Console.WriteLine("Year    Month   WS1_AF    WS1_Rain    WS1_Sun   WS1_TMax    WS1_Tmin");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    string[][] Ws1Data = new[]
    {
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\Year.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\Month.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\WS1_AF.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\WS1_Rain.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\WS1_Sun.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\WS1_TMax.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"\A2Alg\files\WS1_TMin.txt"),



    };
                    int nRows = Ws1Data[0].Length;
                    int nColumns = Ws1Data.Length;
                    string tempString = " ";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
                    {
                        tempString = " ";
                        for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
                        {
                            tempString = tempString + Ws1Data[j][i];
                            tempString = tempString + "    ";
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(tempString);
                    }
```

The code above reads all the files and outputs it all into one array, it works but I need a way to search a year and then output the data linked to that year.

Comment: So the year is in the first column `Ws1Data[j][0]` of the array, is it correct?

Comment: @MachineLearning yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to filter by year.

```
var filter = Ws1Data.Where(row => row[0] == "2016").ToArray();
```

or the following, if you're working with a transpose matrix

```
var filter = Ws1Data.Select((row,i) => row.Where((x,j)  => Ws1Data[0][j] == ("2016")).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

From your output code, this would be the replacement

```
nRows = filter[0].Length;
nColumns = filter.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
{
    tempString = " ";
    for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
    {
        tempString = tempString + filter[j][i];
        tempString = tempString + "    ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(tempString);
}
```

This is a full **demo**

```
            string [][] Ws1Data = new string[3][];
            Ws1Data[0] = new string[3] { "2015", "2016", "2016" };
            Ws1Data[1] = new string[3] { "5asda", "6asda","7asa" };
            Ws1Data[2] = new string[3] { "5sdfdf", "6asda","6dsfsdf" };
            var filter = Ws1Data.Select((row,i) => row.Where((x,j)  => Ws1Data[0][j] == ("2016")).ToArray()).ToArray();

            int nRows = Ws1Data[0].Length;
            int nColumns = Ws1Data.Length;
            string tempString = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            {
                tempString = " ";
                for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
                {
                    tempString = tempString + Ws1Data[j][i];
                    tempString = tempString + "    ";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(tempString);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Filtered by 2016");
            nRows = filter[0].Length;
            nColumns = filter.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            {
                tempString = " ";
                for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
                {
                    tempString = tempString + filter[j][i];
                    tempString = tempString + "    ";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(tempString);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I get string[][] does not contain a definition for where when I implement the code into my code

Comment: doesnt matter, sorted it

Comment: What do you mean? You can use filter instead of Ws1Data to show only one year: what's the problem? Please explain, thanks

Comment: Ok, so if it works, please mark this as answer, thanks

Comment: So to get it to output the filter in my console do i just use Console.WriteLine(filter); ???

Comment: in this part of the code. for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) on the output code, i get the error a local or parameter i can not be declared in this scope

Comment: You already have that line in your original code, so you're messing something else up. Insert the code carefully. Also,  notice my edit, maybe you have a " transpose matrix"

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Thank you ever so much!!